# Building hector_quadrotor failed

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Hi, I have installed ROS and Gazebo and I tried to build this project:**

> http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo

**After I executing**

> rosmake hector_quadrotor_demo

**All things work well unless I meet these errors:**

> ......
>
> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> mkdir -p bin
>
> cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
> ..
>
> -- The C compiler identification is
> GNU
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification
> is GNU
>
> -- Check for working C compiler:
> /usr/bin/gcc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler:
> /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info -
> done
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler:
> /usr/bin/c++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler:
> /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info -
> done
>
> -- Found PythonInterp:
> /usr/bin/python (found version
> "2.7.3")
>
> [rosbuild] Building package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
>
> Failed to invoke
> /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack
> deps-manifests
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
>
> [rospack] Error: package/stack
> 'hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins'
> depends on non-existent package
> 'hector_gazebo_plugins' and rosdep
> claims that it is not a system
> dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> or try calling 'rosdep update'
>
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129
> (message):
>
> ```
> Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
>
> 'hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins'.  Look above for errors from rospack
>
> itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> ```
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203
> ```
>
> (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
>
> ```
> CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
> ```
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors
> occurred!
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
>
> [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
> written to:
>
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/hongbo-miao/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130203-101443/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/build_output.log
>
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins [FAIL]
> [ 2.95 seconds ]
>
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins.
>
> [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads
> to complete.
>
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> hector_uav_msgs [PASS] [ 112.02
> seconds ]
>
> [ rosmake ] Results:
>
> [ rosmake ] Built 69 packages with 1
> failures.
>
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
>
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/hongbo-miao/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130203-101443

**If I continue executing**

> roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo
> indoor_slam_gazebo.launch

**I will get this error:**

> cannot locate
> [indoor_slam_gazebo.launch] in package
> [hector_quadrotor_demo]

**Can somebody help me? Thank you very much.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1174/building-hector_quadrotor-failed/) by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/188/hongbo-miao/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Buyval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182/alex-buyval/) on 2013-02-04**:
Which version of ROS have you installed?  Have you done initialize rosdep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, @Alex Buyval, I have got the answer from ROS Q&A Forum. Anyway, thank you for your quick response.

The respondent on ROS Q&A Forum said that information about required stacks was indeed incomplete in the tutorials. And he has added the missing stacks in the prerequisites section.

Hope this can help guys who meet the same problem. For more details, please see:

> http://answers.ros.org/question/54111/building-hector_quadrotor-failed/

---

Originally posted by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/188/hongbo-miao/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0